# Enabling IOMMU in the kernel for graphics card pass-through

Tags: virtualbox, linux-kernel, grub2, pci

**Short question:**

How can I turn on the `intel_iommu` setting in the Linux kernel? I run a Debian host, using the grub2 bootloader. Documentation I've seen says to edit `/boot/grub/menu.lst`, which seems to be relevant only for grub 1.x, as I don't have that file.

It is my understanding (and last option I can think of) that changing this boot option might get rid of the following error message in `/var/log/kern.log`

```
vboxpci: No IOMMU domain (attach)
```

**Long question:**

**Giving a guest OS direct access to graphics card**

I recently realised that it's possible to pass through a PCI-express device to guest OS's running in Virtualbox. Cool, I thought! I've got two NVIDIA Quadro FX graphics cards (with SLI bridge connection in place, which I hope isn't causing the grief) and would like to dedicate the 2nd graphics card to the guest OS, so that I can use OpenGL features within Photoshop et al.

NVIDIA market this "[SLI Multi-OS](http://www.nvidia.com/object/sli_multi_os.html)" configuration, which is basically what I've wanted to set up for ages, but I don't want to spend over a grand on the Virtualisation software (Parallels workstation extreme), when I have been using VirtualBox quite happily for years now.

**Host System**

I'm running linux-3.5.0-19 from the Debian repositories, on quite high-end workstation equipment (Asus P6T7 WS Supercomputer mobo w/ Intel ICH10R chipset and Xeon W3680 CPU) and would like to turn on IOMMU support in the kernel, preferably without having to compile it myself.

**BIOS**

In the BIOS settings, I have VT-x and VT-d support enabled. I couldn't see anything specifically mentioning IOMMU, though.

**Attaching the PCI device**

This was pleasantly surprisingly simple! The official VirtualBox documentation is [here](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#pcipassthrough). What I did, which I found less ambiguous, was to open `nvidia-settings`, select the secondary graphics card and note the Bus ID ("PCI:5:0:0" in my case). Then, from the host's command line:-

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "Windows Guest" --pciattach 05:00.0
```

(When I first ran this, there was an error because VirtualBox was emulating a PIIX chipset; it said that PCI pass-through only works with ICH9 chipsets. So I changed the Chipset to ICH9 in the VirtualBox VM System settings and turned on the guest to install the necessary new drivers. A reboot later and everything was working fine, so I shut down the guest, and re-ran the command.)

There was no output, and I was returned to the command line almost immediately.

**Using host GPU from the guest**

Before turning on the guest, I first rebooted the host machine, in case something undocumented needed to happen in the kernel, by virtualbox-dkms. As I ran the previous command without `sudo` privileges, I doubt any changes were made, though.

When I next started the guest, Windows Update started doing its thing and automatically detected and installed the correct NVIDIA drivers. All looking good so far. Before I could use the device though, I had to reboot the guest...

**Problem**

Now that the graphics card drivers are installed on the guest and the PCI device attached, I can't get into the Windows desktop. I get to the Windows login screen, then after logging in, the screen freezes, just saying "Welcome", with a should-be-spinning-but-isn't blue circle next to it.

In `/var/log/kern.log`, the last messages printed are:-

```
vboxpci: vboxPciOsDevInit: dev=500
vboxpci: detected device: 10de:05ff at 05:00.0, driver pci-stub
vboxpci: vboxPciOsDevInit: dev=500 pdev=ffff88061bea0000
pci-stub 0000:05:00.0: irq 76 for MSI/MSI-X
vboxpci: enabled MSI
500: linux vboxPciOsDevGetRegionInfo: reg=0
got mmio region: fa000000:16777216
500: linux vboxPciOsDevGetRegionInfo: reg=1
got mmio region: d0000000:268435456
500: linux vboxPciOsDevGetRegionInfo: reg=3
got mmio region: f8000000:33554432
500: linux vboxPciOsDevGetRegionInfo: reg=5
got pio region: 8c00:128
500: linux vboxPciOsDevGetRegionInfo: reg=6
got mmio region: fb980000:524288
got PCI IRQ: 76
device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
power state: 0
vboxpci: No IOMMU domain (attach)
```

Any idea how to fix this?

**UPDATE:**

I've got the kernel booting now with `intel_iommu=on`, but things still aren't working fully.. After rebooting the host, the guest starts, logs in okay and everything seems as it was before starting any of this. My 2nd graphics card isn't outputting anything.

In Device Manager, there is an exclamation mark next to the Quadro FX device, and there is an error code of 12 in the device properties, with a message saying "This device cannot find enough free resources". Further description on [technet.microsoft.com](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732199%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

In the host kernel log, it looks promising:-

```
vboxpci: detected device: 10de:05ff at 05:00.0, driver pci-stub
vboxpci: vboxPciOsDevInit: dev=500 pdev=ffff88061baa0000
pci-stub 0000:05:00.0: irq 76 for MSI/MSI-X
vboxpci: enabled MSI
500: linux vboxPciOsDevGetRegionInfo: reg=0
got mmio region: fa000000:16777216
500: linux vboxPciOsDevGetRegionInfo: reg=1
got mmio region: d0000000:268435456
500: linux vboxPciOsDevGetRegionInfo: reg=3
got mmio region: f8000000:33554432
500: linux vboxPciOsDevGetRegionInfo: reg=5
got pio region: 8c00:128
500: linux vboxPciOsDevGetRegionInfo: reg=6
got mmio region: fb980000:524288
got PCI IRQ: 76
created IOMMU domain ffff88058377c9a0
device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
power state: 0
vboxpci: iommu_attach_device() success
```

If I start the guest OS a second time, without rebooting the host, the display freezes again at the "Welcome" stage. It definitely finishes the log-in stage though, as I could use windows shortcuts to shutdown the machine without forcing a shutdown..

Now I'm kind of out of ideas... Any suggestions to get this working? Any more info I can provide?

**UPDATE2:**

`dmesg` contains some more interesting errors, but I don't know what I can do about them:

```
IOMMU 0 0xfbfff000: using Queued invalidation
IOMMU 1 0xfbffe000: using Queued invalidation
------------[ cut here ]------------
WARNING: at /build/buildd/linux-3.5.0/drivers/iommu/intel-iommu.c:4254 init_dmars+0x39b/0x74f()
Hardware name: System Product Name

Your BIOS is broken; DMA routed to ISOCH DMAR unit but no TLB space.

BIOS vendor: American Megatrends Inc.; Ver: 0811   ; Product Version: System Version
...
Your BIOS is broken; RMRR ends before it starts!
```

Comment: The IOMMU setting should be active by default on Debian stable if the hardware supports it. Since it was causing trouble and tons of errors in the log I had to deactivate it with `intel_iommu=soft`. You can try passing `intel_iommu=on`.

Comment: Cool, just found the file and line where to change this; KDE's grub-config module put `CONFIG_CMDLINE_LINUX=intel_iommu=on` in to `/etc/default/grub`. Now the guest boots, but doesn't detect the graphics card...

Comment: `intel_iommu=soft` doesn't seem to be a valid kernel option, and when I used it, it reverted to `intel_iommu=on`.. From [www.kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt), you can have `iommu=soft`, but I can't find any documentation for that.. Do you know what it does?

Comment: You're right, it's `iommu=soft`. It deactivates the hardware IOMMU (which causes numerous DMA errors on my system) and uses a software IOMMU instead. Here's a link to an old thread: [Suggestion to use iommu=soft for all kernel packages](http://www.mail-archive.com/debian-kernel@lists.debian.org/msg23378.html)

Comment: Thanks. I might give that a shot when I next reboot. I think all my hardware supports IOMMU, though, so not sure if a software emulation would be a good idea.  
On a related note, not sure if my GPU has a DMAR unit, and whether it would be a good idea to use `intel_iommu=igfx_off`...

Comment: DMAR is part of your Intel chipset. Make sure you have VT-d enabled in the BIOS.

Comment: `RMRR ends before it starts!` ouch :D

Answer (score 2):

I got VGA passthrough working with an NVIDIA GTX 760 using KVM as a hypervisor with vfio-vga; I have never tried it with Virtualbox. It was a pain, but works well after getting the configuration right. KVM is just as convenient as Virtualbox for quick VMs from your desktop and you might consider it as another option.

This thread has tons of information on lots of different configurations and troubleshooting steps, and was really helpful: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=162768

Comment: Does CUDA work?

Comment: That blog now claims to be outdated and recommends http://vfio.blogspot.com/

Comment: Well, setting up an efficient KVM+qemu from cold ground up might not be that fast.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky, Currently to get CUDA to work, a specific Linux kernel has to be used: https://superuser.com/a/1392031/109803

Answer (score 0):

If your Nvidia driver is saying it couldn't find enough free resources, try disabling the emulated "Standard VGA Adapter" in Device Manager. Reboot the guest, and you may find the following happens, in order:

1) Your VM POST/boot happens on the emulated VGA adapter.
2) The emulated VGA adapter goes blank just before it gets to the login screen
3) Nvidia driver loads and brings up the passthrough GPU, and you get the login screen on the Nvidia card.

With a bit of luck, you might find that things work fine from there on. This is more or less exactly what happens on my similar setup with Xen. Please, do report results. :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have two separate issues. Getting rebooting to work with VGA pass through can be a real bear. In Xen, the VGA device often shows up as a removable device and some people have had better luck "ejecting" the device before rebooting.

The code 12 error can probably be fixed by simply disabling the virtual video device in the Windows device manager.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting one of these in `/etc/grub`:

- `iommu=memmaper`
- `iommu=soft`
- `vga=normal`
- `vesa=0`

I have new AMD 64bit system and found that Linux has trouble with Nvidia and DMA setting caused by iommu settings in BIOS, so setting these in grub fixed it for me.

Read [this for more detail](ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/270.29/README/dma_issues.html).

Answer (score -1):

tested on HP dc7900 to see message "IOMMU found" :

deactivate integrated video

```
iommu=calgary intel_iommu=on intel_iommu=igfx_off
```