# vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I'm running Arch with 3.6.10 kernel,

When vboxpci module is loaded, it tells me `vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)`,

But I checked my kernel config, I have the INTEL_IOMMU set already (I uses a Thinkpad X220)

```
CONFIG_GART_IOMMU=y
# CONFIG_CALGARY_IOMMU is not set
CONFIG_IOMMU_HELPER=y
CONFIG_IOMMU_API=y
CONFIG_IOMMU_SUPPORT=y
# CONFIG_AMD_IOMMU is not set
CONFIG_INTEL_IOMMU=y
CONFIG_INTEL_IOMMU_DEFAULT_ON=y
CONFIG_INTEL_IOMMU_FLOPPY_WA=y
# CONFIG_IOMMU_STRESS is not set
```

Kernel command:

> BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-linux root=/XX processor.ignore_ppc=1
>   apparmor=1 security=apparmor intel_iommu=on

Any suggestions? Althrough VBox starts, but still wondering why.

Comment: What does `dmesg | grep -i iommu` show? In my case VT-d as it's called was disabled in the BIOS on some machine.

Comment: @gertvdijk Nothing but kernel cmd line; Looks like i5 2450m doesn't have VT-d feature

Comment: Indeed. [Intel ARK page](http://ark.intel.com/products/53452/Intel-Core-i5-2450M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz#infosectionadvancedtechnologies) confirms it. You'll have to live without this feature.

Comment: I have bad experience with hardware IOMMU (which doesn't mean it's a bad technology, it just means that it didn't work on *my* systems). I always switch it off. See my comments: [Enabling IOMMU in the kernel for graphics card pass-through](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56777/enabling-iommu-in-the-kernel-for-graphics-card-pass-through)